# Simply if statement to a Tenerary in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ternary

I'm new to Rails and was wondering about the following:

Is there a way to simplify this further?

```
  animal = Animal.find_by(name:name, type:type)
  if !animal
    animal = Animal.create(name:name, type:type)
```

I was thinking of using a ternary expression but i'm wondering how I would write that without repeating code or if this is the correct way of doing it.

```
animal = Animal.find_by(name:name, type:type) ? Animal.find_by(name:name, type:type) :  Animal.create(name:name, type:type);
```

Comment: Did you look at `find_or_create_by`?

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: @SebastianPalma i'm using Rails v5.2.2

Comment: There's also `create_with` and `find_by`, which can be chained in a similar fashion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [find_or_create_by](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

```
animal = Animal.find_or_create_by(name: name, type: type)
```

Comment: awesome! i'm guessing this works with multiple attributes? I'll double check if this is compatible with rails v5

Comment: If you are using rails 6 or higher then use `Animal.create_or_find_by(name:name, type:type)` to avoid possible race conditions. It might never become an issue in your current application. But it will save you from some grey hair in the future :) You can read why this method was introduced here: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2019/03/25/rails-6-adds-create_or_find_by.html

Comment: @IvanDenysov if I'm using rails 5 do you know what's the best way that I can avoid the race conditions?

Comment: @lost9123193 here's a great answer I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917936/2886945
Looks a lot messier than built-in solution from rails 6 :)

Comment: @IvanDenysov `create_or_find_by` (cf) has different behaviour than `find_or_create_by` (fc). cf first tries to create a record, if it fails due to a unique constraint the record is fetched instead. fc first tries to find the record, if it can't be found it is created. If there is no unique constraint over the *name*, *type* or *name/type* combo your suggestion will always create a record.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific scenario the [answer of Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58700855/3982562) is the better answer. However I'd like to offer a clean solution of what you currently have.

Ruby allows an inline modifier-if/unless statement. This would look like this:

```
animal = Animal.find_by(name: name, type: type)
animal = Animal.create(name: name, type: type) unless animal
```

You could also make use of the `||=` operator here (which has my preference). This operator only assigns the right had value to the variable if the variable currently holds a falsy value (`nil` or `false`).

```
animal = Animal.find_by(name: name, type: type)
animal ||= Animal.create(name: name, type: type)

# or if you prefer the longer one-liner
animal = Animal.find_by(name: name, type: type) || Animal.create(name: name, type: type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more variation:

```
animal = Animal.find_by(name:name, type:type) || Animal.create(name:name, type:type)
```